# quering a data with multiple collections in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I have a question on multiple collections in mongoDB.

I have 3 collections in my database and the collections names are Building, History and basic_amenities.

My question is, i want to retrieve the data of  building ,history and basi_amenties to a particular building . I mean i want the data from building ,history and basic_amenities.

I want to do using aggregate concept. Is it possible to do like that or else is there any alternative method.

**Building:**

```
{
    "_id" : "B1",
    "Sale_type" : "Rental",
    "Building_name" : "swamy",
    "Available_apartments" : {
        "Apartment_num" : "A6",
        "Apartment_num" : "A9"
    },
    "Owner" : [ 
        "sreekanth Buddha", 
        "sreekanthb6@gmail.com"
    ],
    "Address" : {
        "Street" : "blumenstrasse",
        "Plot_no" : "13",
        "City" : "Hamburg",
        "State" : "lower saxony",
        "Country" : "Germany",
        "Postal_code" : "68245"
    },
    "Rental" : {
        "Currency" : "EUR",
        "Rental_price" : "10000",
        "Available_date" : "02.03.2015",
        "Deposit_amount" : "60000 EUR"
    },
    "Total_area" : "1200 sq meters",
    "Apartment_id" : [ 
        {
            "id1" : "A1"
        }, 
        {
            "id2" : "A5"
        }, 
        {
            "id3" : "A7"
        }, 
        {
            "id4" : "A2"
        }, 
        {
            "id5" : "A9"
        }
    ],
    "Features" : {
        "No_of_apartments" : "70",
        "Community_hall" : "1",
        "Garden" : 3,
        "Office_room" : 1,
        "Parking" : "yes",
        "Play_ground" : "yes"
    }
}
```

**History:**

```
"_id" : "H-B1",
    "Property_id" : "B1",
    "Builtyear" : "April 1995",
    "year_of_registration" : [ 
        {
            "year" : ISODate("1995-04-15T23:00:00.000Z"),
            "name" : "krishna malli"
        }, 
        {
            "year" : ISODate("2008-07-16T23:00:00.000Z"),
            "name" : "manoj kumar alluri"
        }, 
        {
            "year" : ISODate("2014-10-29T23:00:00.000Z"),
            "name" : "Ram dev swamy"
        }
    ],
    "Renovate" : [ 
        {
            "1995" : " building painting Renovated"
        }, 
        {
            "2008" : " pipeline system was renovated"
        }, 
        {
            "2014" : " roof was renovated"
        }
    ]
}

**Basic_amenities:**


{
    "_id" : "BA-B1",
    "Property_id" : "B1",
    "hospital " : "5 km",
    "bahn_station" : "6 km ",
    "restaurant" : "4 km",
    "University" : "20 km",
    "police_station" : "8 km",
    "Airport" : "40 km",
    "city_center" : " 5 km",
    "Public_transp_type" : [ 
        {
            "Bus" : "35"
        }, 
        {
            "tram" : "5"
        }, 
        {
            "train_station" : "5km"
        }
    ],
    "keylandmark" : "Altstadt",
    "future_activity" : "church constructing"
}
```

Can anyone help me how to query this data  using aggregations concept or else is there any alternative method?  please help me

Regards
Sreekanth

Comment: MongoDB queries can never span more than a single collection, so you need to query each collection separately.

Comment: Hallo Johnny....then,  How to retrieve  a data with two collections in mongoDB?  I have an idea to my question but i dont know im correct or wrong.... i have 3 collections among them( collection 1 + collection 2) i will retrieve data for two collections and i will store that result in a variable. similarly for the collection 2 + collection 3 and i will store that result in a another variable...at last i will join those two collections. Is it possible to do like that.